# Material Ui React - navbar not aligning box to right

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]
I have a navbar that is suppose to align all the page options to the right. However, it does not do this. The entire toolbar is a `flexbox` and I've tried using `alignSelf: end` but this would only move the text slightly downwards.

I am not sure why it does this because the orientation I've chosen for the toolbar is row and not column.

I have tried removing the options that appear when the screen resizes but this did not work either.

Below is the code that is the issue. I've also commented as to which box is causing the issue. (comment labeled ISSUE)

```
          {/* Issue */}
      {/* ABOUT, PROJECTS, CONTACT - full screen */}
      <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },  alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <Button
            key={page}
            onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
            sx={{ my: 2, color: 'black', display: 'block' }}
          >
            {page}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </Box>
```

The entire code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

const pages = ['About', 'Projects', 'Contact'];

const NavBar = () => {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };


  return (
    <AppBar position="static" sx={{backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters sx={{display: { xs: 'flex' }, flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: "blue"}}>

          {/* LOGO */}
          <Typography
            variant="h2"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            color="black"
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}
          >
            name
          </Typography>

          {/*Drawer - small screen  */}
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none'} }}>

            {/* Menu triple bar */}
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>

            {/* ABOUT, PROJECTS, CONTACT - small screen */}
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>

          {/* LOGO - small screen */}
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            color="black"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}
          >
            name
          </Typography>

          {/* Issue */}
          {/* ABOUT, PROJECTS, CONTACT - full screen */}
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },  alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'black', display: 'block' }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to use justifyContent or justifySelf to move content on the main axis and alignContent and alignSelf to move content on cross axis, you were using the wrong CSS property since the main axis in this case is row. For more info. regarding flexbox axes please refer to [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
2. Let me simplify this for you.
3. The work around is fairly easy. The parent Container has two children "Logo/Typography" and "Box", you want the "Box" child to move at the end of the container, you just need to give parent (Toolbar) `justifyContent: space-between` property to make sure both children are at opposite ends.

Play around with the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-sandbox-forked-s0j4rn?file=/src/Components/APPBAR.js:2903-3264)

[image]

```
<AppBar position="static" sx={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar
          disableGutters
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "flex" },
            flexDirection: "row",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            justifyContent: "space-between"
          }}
        >
          {/* LOGO */}
          <Typography
            variant="h2"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            color="black"
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}
          >
            name
          </Typography>

          {/*Drawer - small screen  */}
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
            {/* Menu triple bar */}
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>

            {/* ABOUT, PROJECTS, CONTACT - small screen */}
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left"
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: "block", md: "none" }
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>

          {/* LOGO - small screen */}
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            color="black"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}
          >
            name
          </Typography>

          {/* Issue */}
          {/* ABOUT, PROJECTS, CONTACT - full screen */}
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" }
            }}
          >
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: "black", display: "block" }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
```